# Nested Variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables, nested, nested-attributes

I think I am either just stupid or something but I still can't get my head around them.

I am trying to access "patient_age" from this variable $result.

Here is the var dump.

```
array(1) {
  ["intervention"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#23 (21) {
     ["intervention_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["patient_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["name_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["department_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["dosage_id"]=>
      NULL
      ["edocument"]=>
      string(10) "Bruce1.jpg"
      ["user_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["duration"]=>
      string(8) "02:26:00"
      ["submitted"]=>
      string(19) "2011-07-31 19:56:29"
      ["intervention_comment"]=>
      NULL
      ["patient_age"]=>
      string(2) "34"
      ["patient_height"]=>
      string(4) "1.34"
      ["patient_weight"]=>
      string(2) "45"
      ["patient_gender"]=>
      string(4) "Male"
      ["department_name"]=>
      string(10) "Cardiology"
      ["intervention_name_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["intervention_name"]=>
      string(5) "IVH 2"
      ["intervention_description"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["dosage_emitted"]=>
      NULL
      ["dosage_absorbed"]=>
      NULL
      ["dosage_period"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried :

```
$result[0]->patient_age;
$result[1]->patient_age;
$result['intervention']->patient_age;
$result['intervention'][0]->patient_age;
```

Hopefully someone could give me the answer but also explain how they came to this answer as all the other Stackoverflow questions they just give the solution but not the method.

Anyone got any tips how to navigate nested variables.

Thanks

Comment: The last example (`$result['intervention'][0]->patient_age;`) should work - have you checked the error log?

Comment: Sorry it was a type , was $results instead of $result, I feel even more stupid :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be your last example. It's not that hard, really. $result is an array which contains a single element, with the key "intervention". You can access an array's elements by using [ and ]. So, with $result['intervention'], you get an array that also contains a single element: the element at key 0, which is an instance of stdClass. You can reach that by using $result['intervention'][0]. If you want to get the patient_age from that stdClass, you can access the *instance variables* with the ->. So, this should work:

```
echo $result['intervention'][0]->patient_age;
```

The following would result in $patient being the stdClass instance, which you can then retrieve patient_age from:

```
$patient = $result['intervention'][0];
echo $patient->patient_age;
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation , it turns out there was a typo in my variable being passed, was $results should have been $result in my view. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$object=$result['intervention'][0];
print $object->patient_age;
```

Check if any other variables are accessable

Answer (score 0):

> $result[0]->patient_age;

will work *as long as patient_age is a public variable*. If it's private or protected you'll need to use a method within the object to access it.

You never said what happened with the stuff you tried. Null values? Error/warning messages?

Proof:

```
<?php

class iv {
    var $patient_age;
    function __construct($val)
    {
            $this->patient_age=$val;
    }
}

$t=new iv(40);
$result=array(0=>$t);
var_dump($result) . "\n\n";
print "val = " . $result[0]->patient_age . "\n\n";


[user@example ~]$ php -q t.php
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(iv)#1 (1) {
    ["patient_age"]=>
    int(40)
  }
}
val = 40
[user@example ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- Access to deeply nested PHP variables can be done easily and cleanly with JMESPATH

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- PHP version 7.x, 8.x
- PHP addon library JMESPATH
- dealing with complex nested PHP variables

#### Problem

- **Use-case scenario:** Developer wishes to access specific part(s) of a nested PHP variable
- the code should be minimal and easy to understand

#### Solution

- use the JMESPATH addon library for PHP
- use JMESPATH expressions to both access and transform nested PHP variables

#### Basic Example

- Basic Example PHP code to access a value from a PHP variable

  ```
      require 'vendor/autoload.php';
      $lookup = '@.intervention[0].patient_age';
      $result = array(
          "intervention" => array(
              array(
                  "department_id" => "1",
                  "department_name" => "Cardiology",
                  "dosage_absorbed" => null,
                  "dosage_emitted" => null,
                  "dosage_id" => 'uu247pushuprag1652203549',
                  "dosage_period" => null,
                  "duration" => "02:26:00",
                  "edocument" => "Bruce1.jpg",
                  "intervention_comment" => null,
                  "intervention_description" => "",
                  "intervention_id" => "1",
                  "intervention_name" => "IVH 2",
                  "intervention_name_id" => "1",
                  "name_id" => "1",
                  "patient_age" => "34",
                  "patient_gender" => "Male",
                  "patient_height" => "1.34",
                  "patient_id" => "1",
                  "patient_weight" => "45",
                  "submitted" => "2011-07-31 19:56:29",
                  "user_id" => "0"
              )
          )
      );
      JmesPath\search($lookup, $result);
  ```

  > '34'

#### Advantages

- process complex variables with uniform minimal syntax
- avoids having to use loops and temporary variables to store off data

#### Pitfalls

- requires installation of JMESPATH addon which does not come with PHP by default
- requires familiarity with JMESPATH expressions which are not part of the native PHP spec

#### See also

- [jmespath.org](https://jmespath.org/)
- [rethinking loops](https://events.drupal.org/neworleans2016/sessions/rethinking-loops.html)